# Insert columns based on input in C3 and copy all column values

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I Have a worksheet in which we need to automate the number of column entries based on the number of units required.

The cells in each row have formulas based on input parameters and subtotals. The requirement is to insert defined number of columns based on the units required (can be input box or cell reference) which should result in copying all formulas and formats to all columns inserted. The inserted columns should be before the last three columns namely Total, Budget and Variance.

I have found the below code but this is not working for my example.

[image]

```
  Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim LC As Integer
Dim I As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
If Target.Address <> "$C$3" Then Exit Sub
If Target.Value = "" Or Target.Value = 0 Then MsgBox "Value must be superior to 0": Exit Sub
LC = Cells(2, Application.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
If LC = 5 Then
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
         Exit Sub
     Else
          For I = 2 To Target.Value
              Columns(4).Copy
              Columns(I + 3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
              Cells(2, I + 3).Value = "Unit " & I
              Cells(3, I + 3) = I
          Next I
      End If
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      Exit Sub
 End If
  Range(Cells(2, 5), Cells(2, LC - 1)).EntireColumn.Delete
 For I = 2 To Target.Value
      Columns(4).Copy
      Columns(I + 3).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
      Cells(2, I + 3).Value = "Unit " & I
      Cells(3, I + 3) = I
 Next I
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Kindly help me with a solution to this problem.

Please let me know how I can send the worksheet for your reference.
Thanks,

Best regards,
Thomas

Comment: You should also try to include a description of what "not working for my example" means. This will make it easier for us to determine what part of your code could be causing the problems :)

Comment: Dear Sir, initially this code was working when the input in cell C3 was the number of units and the last column was Totals only.

Comment: Dear Sir, after changes to the sheet format by insertion of two columns after C3 and by addition of two columns after totals, now when entry for units is carried out in C3, all the values in the units columns are deleted and the last column in the Variance column.

Comment: Do the "Summary Rows" (the ones labelled "Parameter X Summary") also need to be automatically generated or do you have that working already?

Comment: Dear Sir, the Summary rows are working but the values are getting deleted due to the shift of the columns with respect to the code and hence all  values are blank.

Comment: Dear Sir, can I share an image in the original question to show what is happening now.

Comment: So you want to be able to change the number of parameters whenever you want? In the first picture you showed you already have 5 parameters. If I typed 3 into the Number of Parameters field what do you want to happen?

Comment: Dear Sir, Yes the number of columns inserted from column F changes with every project. In the case of 3 units the number of columns inserted will be 3 from column F:H

Comment: Dear Sirs, kindly help to get this code working, thanks

Comment: Have you tried to do any debugging yourself? Refer to [this](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) helpful guide on how to use the builtin VBA debugger. Try putting a breakpoint into the section where you add columns and step through each iteration.

Comment: Dear Sir, I am a novice at VBA, i am still learning to work in excel. Kindly help me with this solution. My manager needs this sheet to be submitted as soon as possible. Please help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? I am trying to help you help yourself. Debugging is a crucial thing to be able to do, and from the sounds of it you have not attempted to debug your code at all :)